# Undefined references while linking static libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker

My (primarily)C++  project consists of the following structure, creates an executable target with many static libraries linking against it. one such library present in a subdirectory consists of a C++ source file which has a dependency on another c++ source file in the same subdirectory.

I am using CMake with ARM-GNU, with MinGW as Generator.

The two c++ source files are as follows:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"
int serial :: available(void)
{
return usb.available();
}
Serial_ Serial(USBDevice);
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"
int USBDeviceClass :: available()
{
return something;
}
USBDeviceClass USBDevice;
```

The common header file :
**base.h**

```
class Serial_
{
public:
int available();
} 
extern Serial_ Serial;

class USBDeviceClass
{
public:
int available();
}
extern USBDeviceClass USBDevice;
USBDeviceClass &usb;
```

**My project Structure:**

```
Project(Foo)

  CMakeLists.txt

  application.cpp

  application.hpp

  (subdirectory1)
          CMakeLists.txt

          include

                   A.hpp

                    B.hpp

                   base.h

            src

                   A.cpp

                   B.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
Project(Foo)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C://Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C://Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-x c -mthumb  -D__SAMD21G18A__ -DARM_MATH_CM0 -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD -DUSB_VID=0x239A -DUSB_PID=0x800B  -march=armv6-m -c -std=gnu99 -ffunction-sections -mlong-calls -g3 -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mthumb -D__SAMD21G18A__ -DARM_MATH_CM0 -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD -DUSB_VID=0x239A  -DUSB_PID=0x800B   -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -mlong-calls -march=armv6-m")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-lm -Wl,--gc-sections -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-T\"../flash_without_bootloader.ld\"")   

include_direcctories(subdirectory1/include)
add_executable(Foo.elf application.cpp application.hpp)
add_subdirectory(subdirectory1)
target_link_libraries(Foo.elf PUBLIC Bar)
```

**subdirectory1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(SOURCES 
    A.cpp
    B.cpp
)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(Bar STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

**THE ERROR WHILE TRYING TO BUILD**

```
C://a/b/build : cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
C://a/b/build : make clean && make

Subdirectory1\libBar.a(A.cpp.obj): In function `Serial_::available()':
A.cpp:(.text._ZN7Serial_9availableEv+0x20): undefined reference to `USBDeviceClass::available()'
```

My understanding is that, the problem is because the linker is unable to find the defintions of undefined symbols. (I tried bindump and found UND symbols of **A.cpp.obj**)

**Things I have already tried**

1. extern "C"
2. resolving circular dependency (there wasn't any)
3. Tried to build as Shared Library (which led to " **Non-representable section on output **")

**Does the order of adding SOURCES for **add_library** matter ?**

**How can we make sure that the link order is correct to serve the dependency requirements?**

Any suggestion would be of great help, I have been stuck in this problem for too long now!!

Comment: Error does not match your code. Linker is complaining about missing definition for `USBDeviceClass::available(unsigned long)` and I see that you are using `USBDeviceClass::available()` (probably you have different version of it in your hpp and it is used somewhere else in the code). Remove all "extern" from your code, keep some reasonable naming convention (e.g. don't put underscore in classname if it is supposed to be used publicly), format your code properly. Otherwise everything looks more or less OK, so for sure it is some typo.

Comment: @pptaszni Sorry that is my typo while posting here, not in error/code.

Comment: Mmm yeah, first clean your example anyway. In the current form it will not even compile, so hard to tell what exactly is wrong. I can correct it myself of course, but then I will not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Consider using target_include_directories, and target_sources to clean up your code. Otherwise you are using really old cmake that is hard to read. Just a suggestion.